# When generalized wronskians vanish

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I read the following statement in Wikipedia  [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)  "Thus, the Wronskian can be used to show that a set of differentiable functions is linearly independent on an interval by showing that it does not vanish identically. It may, however, vanish at isolated points.".

I wonder, if it holds true for generalized Wronskian: if a set of linear independent and differentiable functions $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $i=1,\cdots,m$ and $m <n$.

Does its generalized Wronskian vanish at isolated points ?

Tnanks in advance.

Comment: Well sure, since a generalized wronskian becomes a standard wronskian when $D_i=\frac{d^i}{d^ix}$

Comment: Thanks, for your comments.